# Result from two tables order by date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

can you help I have two tables `images` and `note`. I would like to get all items from these tables and order by date. It is possible I am using active record in codeigniter. Tables are independent.

Thank you for replies.

Comment: I tried but it show me error Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION' `SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT images.link,images.date FROM images)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT note.name_slovak,note.date FROM note)
) results
ORDER BY date DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
$this->db->orderby("date", "ASC"); //or desc     
$query = $this->db->get('images'); //or $query = $this->db->get('note');
$result=$query->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

or if you want use union all

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, date FROM images UNION ALL SELECT id, date FROM note) result ORDER BY result.date');
```

Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp.

Comment: Select from two tables same time

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a Cross Join.
Here is your codeigniter code

```
$this->db->from("images ,note");
$this->db->select("images.*,note.*);
//make sure both dont have same column name other wise use this
//$this->db->select("images.column1,images.column2,note.column1);

$this->db->orderby("images.date", "DESC");
//you can add more orderby
//you can add where condition too

$result=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Now you will get the cross product.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In which table do you have date column? I assume you have it in images table.

`$this->db->select('images.coulmn1, images.culmn2, images.date_col, note.col1, note.col2');
$this->db->from('images');
$this->db->join('note', 'note.key1 = images.key1); //key1 is key field to relate both table.
$this->db->order_by("images.date_col", "desc");
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();`

Hope it will help.

Comment: He said that tables are not related.

Comment: I said that tables are independent I cant use join and date column have both.

Comment: ah, sorry. I noticed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('images');
 $this->db->join('note');
 $this->db->orderby("date column name", "ASC");
 $query = $this->db->get();
 $result=$query->result_array();
 print_r($result);
```